# I'm getting error when unit testing a method that calls empty() on an object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

Test is erroring with

```
dataLayerHelper
generateProductLinesDataLayer
extends the datalayer:
ReferenceError: empty is not defined
at Object.generateProductLinesDataLayer (cartridges\gtm\int_gtm_sfra_custom\cartridge\scripts\gtm\dataLayerHelper.js:42:9)
at Context.<anonymous> (cartridges\test\unit\gtm\int_gtm_sfra_custom\scripts\dataLayerHelper.js:59:42)
at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:464:21)
at process.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:131:17)
```

Here:

```
if (!empty(pli.product) && pli.product.isVariant()) {
    pid = pli.product.masterProduct.ID;
    variant = pli.productID;
}
```

Why would I get an error when testing a method that uses a built in empty() method that doesn't require any other reference?

Test:

```
describe("generateProductLinesDataLayer", function () {
        it.only(" extends the datalayer", function () {
            var result = dataLayerHelper.generateProductLinesDataLayer(productLineItems);
            assert.deepEqual(result, []);
        });
    });
```

```
function generateProductLinesDataLayer(productLineItems) {
......
        if (!empty(pli.product) && pli.product.isVariant()) {
            pid = pli.product.masterProduct.ID;
            variant = pli.productID;
        }
......
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The empty() call in the code is what throws the error :
ReferenceError: empty is not defined
This exact line in the code: if (!empty(pli.product) && pli.product.isVariant()) {
empty is not a dependency so not sure why that part of the method being unit tested throws an error.

Comment: JavaScript Expressions The Empty Operator
empty()
Returns true if the object is empty. Empty is defined as:
Note: If the object is never declared, the JavaScript throws a ReferenceError so Empty(object) isn't true.

Comment: Figured it out.  empty() wasn't the problem, what it was checking didn't exist.